# Create multiple aws_lb_listener_rule using for_each for multiple listener_arn

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-application-load-balancer

The main idea is to create the same rules but for different listeners.

I have stuck on `var.listener_rules_http_redirect.listener_arn`. How to process because of `each.value.listener_arn` doesn't work.

Could anyone share fresh ideas, please?

Error:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on modules/aws/alb/lb_listener_rule/03-main.tf line 4, in resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "www_redirect":
│    4:   listener_arn = each.value.listener_arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.listener_arn is tuple with 1 element
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "listener_arn": string required.
```

Module variables

```
module "lb_listener_rule_http" {
  source             = "./modules/aws/alb/lb_listener_rule"
  listener_arn       = module.alb_lb_listener.frontend_http
  tags               = merge(local.tags, { Name = var.domain })
  domain_name_public = var.domain

  listener_rules_http_redirect = {
    // redirect www to non www
    1 = {
      listener_arn = [
        {
          http  = module.alb_lb_listener.frontend_http,
          https = module.alb_lb_listener.frontend_https
        }
      ],
      action = [
        {
          "type"             = "redirect",
          "target_group_arn" = module.target_group.arns[local.target_group_name_wp],
        }
      ],
      redirect = [
        {
          host        = var.domain
          path        = "/#{path}"
          query       = "#{query}"
          port        = "443"
          protocol    = "HTTPS"
          status_code = "HTTP_301"
        }
      ]
      conditions = [
        {
          "field"  = "host-header"
          "values" = ["www.${var.domain}"]
        }
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

module code

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "www_redirect" {
  for_each     = var.listener_rules_http_redirect
  listener_arn = each.value.listener_arn
  priority     = each.key

  dynamic "action" {
    for_each = each.value["action"]

    content {
      type = action.value.type
      dynamic "redirect" {
        for_each = each.value["redirect"]
        content {
          host        = redirect.value.host
          path        = redirect.value.path
          query       = redirect.value.query
          port        = redirect.value.port
          protocol    = redirect.value.protocol
          status_code = redirect.value.status_code
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = each.value["conditions"]
    content {
      dynamic "host_header" {
        for_each = condition.value.field == "host-header" ? [condition.value.field] : []

        content {
          values = condition.value.values
        }
      }
      dynamic "path_pattern" {
        for_each = condition.value.field == "path-pattern" ? [condition.value.field] : []
        content {
          values = condition.value.values
        }
      }
      dynamic "source_ip" {
        for_each = condition.value.field == "source-ip" ? [condition.value.field] : []
        content {
          values = condition.value.values
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Vars

```
variable "listener_rules_http_redirect" {
  type        = map(any)
  default     = {}
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @MarkoE I have added error mesage

Comment: Well, I don't think that can work as you have defined it. To make it work initially, I would probably just create another key, e.g., `2` and add the HTTPS listener there, while `1` would have HTTP listerner ARN defined.